# Bootstrap: Redimensionamento da figure

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-3

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<section class="container sobre-site">
    <h2 id="sobre-site-id" class="subtitulo">Título</h2>

    <figure class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-loja" src="img/espaco/8-1.png" alt="Título">
        <figcaption class="caption">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
                veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
                commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
                velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
            </p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

O resultado para mobile fica da seguinte forma:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o resultado para desktop fica assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu gostaria que o resultado para o desktop ficasse da seguinte forma:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer de várias formas mas estou achando que no boostrap não tem como fazer assim. Ou tem?

Após aplicar o código:

```
@media(min-width: 1024px) {
    .img-loja, .caption  {
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

ficou da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A borda não está englobando todo o conteúdo (imagem e texto)

Comment: Agora estou no telemovel, nao consigo testar mas tente com o texto (p), `margin: 0;`

Comment: Miguel, testei mas não mudou também.

Comment: Mas em baixo, editei e agora não tem margem

Comment: Pois é, eu testei dessa forma .caption p {
  margin: 0;
} mesmo, mas não foi. Você testou no seu e deu certo?

Comment: Sim, pode comprovar em baixo, no exemplo que dei. Acho que tem alguma coisa nos seus css que provocam isso, apague tudo relacionado isto e comece com este meu exemplo em baixo